# How to clear datatable when created dynamically using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

For the first time when i insert data into table it get inserted into datatable tbody. next time when i change data tbody get appened with datatable tbody. I want to remove tbody of datatable for my code to work.

```
 <table frame="hsides" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rules</th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>


$.ajax({url: '../controllers/manage_rule_controller.php',

    type: 'POST',
    data: { "operation": "get_rule"},
    dataType:"json",
        },

         success: function (data) {
         keys = Object.keys(data);
         var table = document.getElementById("table");
         $("#table").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
         var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
         table.appendChild(tBody);

        for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
        {
            var row = tBody.insertRow(i);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 testdiv' id='fullrule"+keys[i]+"'><div style='border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f2' class='col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-8'  id='rule"+keys[i]+"' onclick='updaterule(this)'>"+data[keys[i]]+" </div></div>"

        } var dataTable = $('#table').DataTable();  
    }, 
  });
```

Comment: Try adding `tBody.html("");`before the for loop

Comment: No it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Before calling your ajax and redrawing your datatable,

```
var dataTable = $('#table').DataTable();
dataTable.rows().remove().draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of you are using table.appendChild(tBody), this will append not over write the newly generated html each time. So try to use html() or clear old html before appending new one.